# No outgoing sequence flow of the exclusive gateway 'exclusivegateway8'

Tags: spring-boot, flowable

New to flowable, seeing this error in one of the existing workflow, can someone help to understand this issue ? or navigate to right resource for this. ?

````
 isLogged = false
 reduceLogLevel = false
 detailMessage = "No outgoing sequence flow of the exclusive gateway 'exclusivegateway8' could be selected for continuing the process"
 cause = {FlowableException@16042} "org.flowable.engine.common.api.FlowableException: No outgoing sequence flow of the exclusive gateway 'exclusivegateway8' could be selected for continuing the process"
 stackTrace = {StackTraceElement[129]@16054} 
 suppressedExceptions = {Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList@16055}  size = 0 ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your process there are exclusive gateways. One of those exclusive gateways has the model id `exclusivegateway8`. It looks like that there are conditions on the outgoing sequence flows and in your specific case no of the conditions are met. With that it is not able to continue the process execution.

Answer (score 0):

If you will see in your process you might not given condition for exclusive gateway. So its not the path which way it has go. So that's why its giving message "No outgoing sequence flow of the exclusive gateway ".
Refer below:

```
<bpmn:sequenceFlow id="Flow_0pupuvv" sourceRef="Gateway_0rmpggt" targetRef="Activity_1acatm8">
   <bpmn:conditionExpression xsi:type="bpmn:tFormalExpression">${approved == true}
   </bpmn:conditionExpression>
</bpmn:sequenceFlow>
```